# Delegate only works with the first 2 divs

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a query result and im trying to setup a click function for each result, this results can vary depending on a query that can be executed on demand, and each result is setup inside a div. And im using a delegate function to add the click function to each div. But this is only working for the first two divs. Any ideas? What am I missing?

This is the delegate code

```
$("#preventivos_programados")
        .delegate("div.renglon","click",function(){
            a = $(this).html();
            res = a.split("<br>");
            console.log(res[0] + " " + res[1] + " " + res[2]);
});
```

This is how the parent div looks like, this div will hold all the divs that are being created.

```
<div id="preventivos_programados"></div>
```

Finally this is how the div looks like after the query has been updated.

```
<div id="preventivos_programados">
      <div class="renglon sem_amarillo">33<br>2,999<br>13-March-2014</div>
      <div class="renglon sem_verde">30<br>3,001<br>14-March-2014</div>
      <div class="renglon sem_verde">40<br>346,405<br>20-March-2014</div>
      <div class="renglon sem_verde">65<br>1,171,268<br>20-March-2014</div>
      <div class="renglon sem_verde">38<br>1,944,236<br>28-March-2014</div>
      <div class="renglon sem_verde">104<br>418,764<br>30-March-2014</div>
      <div class="renglon sem_verde">36<br>476,700<br>05-April-2014</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is somewhere else, your code works http://jsfiddle.net/pJKsw/

Comment: Have you try to inspect elements? Aren't any CSS rule or any element put above these DIVs?

Comment: this is all the css that it's applied to thedivs with class "renglon sem_verde" http://pastebin.com/QNNqufyb

Comment: could you provide any online link where we can see that behaviour?

Comment: It turns out its not a CSS rule per se... is just that another div was overlapping on top of my divs http://i.imgur.com/cVqX4Xr.jpg this div belongs to the footer.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
$(document)
    .on("click","div.renglon",function(){
        a = $(this).html();
        res = a.split("<br>");
        console.log(res[0] + " " + res[1] + " " + res[2]);
});
```

Comment: this is not what the user is asking for.. the question is on delegate.

Comment: @TilwinJoy `.delegate()` has been superseded by `.on()`, and this is the proper way to use `.on()` as a delegate. Also, the OP did not say he is restricted to `.delegate()` for legacy reasons.

Comment: still it's not removed. the question's title itself is on why delegate is not working. even i'm eager to know why it's not working, coz the syntax seems right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working one.

```
$("#preventivos_programados")
        .on("click", "div.renglon", function(){
            a = $(this).html();
            res = a.split("<br>");
            console.log(res[0] + " " + res[1] + " " + res[2]);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ev6Zd/)

Comment: The delegate API docs say "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method." 
"Superseded" isn't exactly the same as "deprecated", but it's close.

Comment: this is not what the user is asking for.. the question is on delegate.

Comment: @RakeshKumar you are correct, doesn't mean deprecated and for the less doesn't mean removed. Delegate still works so doesn't explain OP's issue

Comment: I have the same result with on and delegate